# Find Contractors that Only Provided Service2 in Each Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a `project` table. Each row is a service or product for a project.

```
Project  Contractor  Service
=======  ==========  =======
  1         B           S1
  1         A           S2
  1         A           S3
  1         C           S1
  2         D           S2
  2         A           S1
  2         B           S3
  3         E           S2
  3         B           S1
  3         C           S2
```

I want to find contractors that provided S2 on a project and did not provide any other service on the same project they provided S2.

```
1  NULL
2  D
3  E
3  C
```

I pulled the data out in SQL and filtered and grouped it in Excel but I would like to find a way to do it in SQL.  Using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: That works on the simple example data, but it will not always find the contractors that only provided S2, i.e., it doesn't exclude contractors that provided S2 and also may have provided S1 or S3 on the same project.

Comment: maybe you need to enhance your example more. so we know what do you really want

Answer (score 2):

I would go with an anti semi-join (`NOT EXISTS` statement):

```
SELECT AllS2.[Project],
    AllS2.[Contractor],
    AllS2.[Service]
FROM [StackoverflowProjects] AllS2
WHERE AllS2.[Service] = 'S2'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    FROM StackoverflowProjects NonS2
    WHERE AllS2.Project = NonS2.Project 
    AND AllS2.Contractor = NonS2.Contractor 
    AND AllS2.Service <> 'S2')
```

Let me know if you would like help with the explanation.  It does, however, work.

### Update

First let me point out, I renamed the aliases to be less abstract and hopefully more helpful.

> I want to find contractors that provided S2 on a project and did not provide any other service on the same project they provided S2.

I knew from this statement that you wanted contractors that only provided S2 service.  The `NOT` part can be a little tricky if you're not already familiar with the `EXISTS` part.

So let me do the opposite and explain what it does:

```
SELECT AllS2.[Project],
    AllS2.[Contractor],
    AllS2.[Service]
FROM [StackoverflowProjects] AllS2
WHERE AllS2.[Service] = 'S2'
AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    FROM StackoverflowProjects NonS2
    WHERE AllS2.Project = NonS2.Project 
    AND AllS2.Contractor = NonS2.Contractor 
    AND AllS2.Service <> 'S2')
```

The will show you all contractors' projects who performed S2 service as well as any service other than S2.

Also, here's a [link to a blog article](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/search/label/Anti%20Semi%20JOIN) that helped me understand the benefits of Semi Joins (`EXISTS`) and Anti-Semi Joins (`NOT EXISTS`) when I was first learning.

Comment: Is there anything else I can answer for you?

Comment: Can you describe your thought processes from reading my problem to expressing your solution? What key elements in the problem led you to use or craft that solution? It would be helpful to know how you approached the problem to improve my skills.

Comment: So, you looked at the problem in terms of sets. First step, you identified the set of all contractors that provided S2. Second step you excluded from set 1 contractors that provided <> S2. Perhaps you first identified the largest set, then worked toward the final set by subtracting (in this case) or perhaps adding in other cases?

Comment: I'm looking for a methodology to get from reading a problem to an SQL solution. Right now, I read the problem and think about it, and I get stumped when faced with an unfamiliar problem like the one I posted here that you solved so neatly.

Comment: Regarding set base, that is correct.  I wish I could share my complete thought process, but the solution just came to me from past struggles similar to what you faced.  That's what makes collaboration like this so great.  We can share our experiences, struggles,  and solutions ... and we all improve by it.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH ServiceCount AS (
    -- Contractor projects that have only one service
    SELECT Project, Contractor, COUNT(*) as [Count]
    FROM Projects
    GROUP BY Project, Contractor
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT
    sc.Project,
    sc.Contractor
FROM ServiceCount sc
JOIN Projects p
    ON p.Project = sc.Project
    AND p.Contractor = sc.Contractor
WHERE p.Service = 'S2'
```

Comment: The GROUP BY is against Project and Contractor. It will give you the projects that a single contractor only provided one service on. Isn't that what you're asking for? And then the filter is on the S2 service.